# Picking LHS column and RHS column of data.table assignment using other column values in R

Tags: r

Here is the code to produce a sample dataset:

```
require(data.table)
testdata <- data.table(
  X = rep(sample(1:3),5),
  Y = rep(sample(1:3),5),
  X1 = rnorm(15),
  X2 = rnorm(15),
  X3 = rnorm(15),
  Y1 = NA_character_,
  Y2 = NA_character_,
  Y3 = NA_character_
)
```

Initial data table:

```
    X Y         X1          X2          X3 Y1 Y2 Y3
 1: 3 3 -0.7098927  0.63342935  0.94470612 NA NA NA
 2: 1 2  0.3008547 -1.40043977  1.53781754 NA NA NA
 3: 2 1  0.3423140  0.34897695 -0.38402565 NA NA NA
 4: 3 3 -0.5726456 -2.24526957 -1.10947867 NA NA NA
 5: 1 2 -1.3239474 -0.53924617 -0.04103982 NA NA NA
 6: 2 1  0.2493801  0.85806647  0.96488021 NA NA NA
 7: 3 3 -2.0653505  0.05481703  1.75161043 NA NA NA
 8: 1 2 -1.3919774  0.34282832  0.50834289 NA NA NA
 9: 2 1  0.5928025 -1.11899399  0.35967102 NA NA NA
10: 3 3 -0.4704720  0.64004313 -0.17343794 NA NA NA
11: 1 2  0.3056093  2.14544631  0.43740447 NA NA NA
12: 2 1 -0.1568971  1.05091249  1.18884487 NA NA NA
13: 3 3 -1.3078670  1.07482123 -0.65367957 NA NA NA
14: 1 2  0.4622123 -0.60308532 -1.11104235 NA NA NA
15: 2 1 -0.7894978  0.33018926 -0.04700393 NA NA NA
```

Here is the action I want to perform:
In each row,

```
if X = 2 and Y = 3 then Y3 <- X2
```

Expected Output:

```
    X Y         X1          X2          X3 Y1                 Y2                 Y3
 1: 3 3 -0.7098927  0.63342935  0.94470612 NA                 NA                 0.94470612
 2: 1 2  0.3008547 -1.40043977  1.53781754 NA                 0.3008547          NA
 3: 2 1  0.3423140  0.34897695 -0.38402565 0.34897695         NA                 NA
 4: 3 3 -0.5726456 -2.24526957 -1.10947867 NA                 NA                 -1.10947867
 5: 1 2 -1.3239474 -0.53924617 -0.04103982 NA                 -1.3239474         NA
 6: 2 1  0.2493801  0.85806647  0.96488021 0.85806647         NA                 NA
 7: 3 3 -2.0653505  0.05481703  1.75161043 NA                 NA                 1.75161043
 8: 1 2 -1.3919774  0.34282832  0.50834289 NA                 -1.3919774         NA
 9: 2 1  0.5928025 -1.11899399  0.35967102 -1.11899399        NA                 NA
10: 3 3 -0.4704720  0.64004313 -0.17343794 NA                 NA                 -0.17343794
11: 1 2  0.3056093  2.14544631  0.43740447 NA                 0.3056093          NA
12: 2 1 -0.1568971  1.05091249  1.18884487 1.05091249         NA                 NA
13: 3 3 -1.3078670  1.07482123 -0.65367957 NA                 NA                 -0.65367957
14: 1 2  0.4622123 -0.60308532 -1.11104235 NA                 0.4622123          NA
15: 2 1 -0.7894978  0.33018926 -0.04700393 0.33018926         NA                 NA
```

How can I achieve this using simple data.table syntax? I have tried get, eval(parse) etc but running into trouble each time.

Note that my actual dataset is quite large(100 plus columns) so I require a solution that doesn't rely on column numbers. I can possible write a large number of if statements as well but it looks like a bad way to do this for about 30 odd columns that need to be assigned in a similar way.

data.table version is 1.10.4 and the R version is 3.3.2

Edit: I solved it using a function. Not sure if this is the best way though as it is very very slow.

```
populateY <- function(input_table) {

  for(i in 1:nrow(input_table)) {
    k <- X
    j <- Y
    tempX <- paste0("input_table$X",k,"[i]")
    tempY <- paste0("input_table$Y",j,"[i]")
    eval(parse(text = paste0(tempY," <- ",tempX)))
  }    
  return(input_table)
}
```

Comment: Try `testdata[X==2 & Y==3, Y3 := X2][]`

Comment: There are several permutations and many more variables for me to lay out all the combinations in such a way. Even in this simple example, there can be 9 such lines of code. So I would like a neater solution if possible @akrun

Comment: @Geep you should explicit with everything you require in your solution. I suggest editing your original post

Comment: @ChiPak ... have added more clarity on the example dataset and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using the tidyverse and tibble data frames, I would do it this way.

```
require(tibble)
testdata <- as_tibble(testdata)

testdata <- testdata %>%
  mutate(Y3 = ifelse(X == 2 & Y == 3, X2, NA))
```

You can then add all the lines you need easily and legibly in the mutate function.

Else if you're going to use data.tables for sure, then I'd go with akrun's suggestion, though you'll need change the data type of column Y3 to double, or just not have it exist when you run that code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I was hoping to find a way to do this programmatically using the values stored in columns X and Y rather than write several if statements as I have to update 30+ variables based on 5 different possibilities each in column X/Y

Comment: You could do it programmatically if there was some structure to the variables you wanted to create, then you could loop or apply to generate those.   But it's difficult in the abstract to tell you how to generate 30+ variables in any way other than "create them" if there isn't a pattern to follow.

Comment: Ok.. I do have a structure for the variables similar to the X1,X2,X3 and Y1,Y2,Y3 structure in the example. The values held in the columns X and Y also correspond to this structure. I ended up writing a function that may or may not be the best way to do it.. I will add that to the question..

Comment: I'll give it a bit more time to see if any other solutions come up.. the solutions you and akrun have proposed are indeed valid and I shall mark this as the answer so if there is no better way ... the function I wrote is working very very slowly ... thanks